# How to get user dictionary in Google translate Api

Tags: c#, .net, google-translate

I would like to make some website with remembered translations in google translate. I think that getting user saved translations is not possible but maybe anyone know some way to do this. I saw that google translate api provide not many endpoints, there is endpoints for detecting languages, translatios and providing available languages. 
Does anyone know how to get saved vocabulary?

[image]

Comment: by saved/user vocabulary you mean the phrasebook that can be inspected from https://translate.google.com/ when logged in?

Comment: I'm not sure if we meaning the same. In the picture i marked the section with saved user words.

Comment: Yes, we mean the same. See my answer.

Comment: Would you please confirm whether the provided answer is helpful or not?

Comment: Sure, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve the saved vocabulary (aka [phrasebook](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142480?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en))

There is an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35881350) asking for some sort of access (a Phrasebook API?) to this data. I'd suggest you to star the issue and show your interest, in order to attract its developer's attention and increase the chances that'll be implemented.